# Javascript: blob link doesn't work

Tags: javascript, blob, mp4, video.js

I'm trying to start a simple blob connection, without letting the video load completely:

```
var video = document.getElementById('video'),
source = document.createElement('source'),
URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL,
file = new Blob(
    //many attempts
    1)["video/play.mp4"],
    2)["c:/xampp/htdocs/video/play.mp4"],
    3)["../video/play.mp4"],
    {type : "video/mp4"}
),
value = URL.createObjectURL(file);
source.src = value;
video.appendChild(source);
```

I have also installed readers like 'videojs', but I can not get it started.
The generated url is always a blob, but I never see the video load, you know why?

Comment: Blob expects the raw content, not a link to it. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob

Comment: And you can't access a file path from the client's computer within JavaScript, even if that was the correct usage of the `Blob` constructor. In addition, a `Blob` by definition contains the full buffered data of the file it represents, so it _has_ to be loaded completely. Try initializing a `<video>` element instead, and give it a URL, not a file path.

Comment: Very interesting answers, but then how can I upload a video to the client's computer via blobs? Do I have to split the video into mini packages and make an ajax call?